# Catalyst - Opening context menu programmatically

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst

I'm using a context menu in my catalyst app by using

```
let interaction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
editButton.addInteraction(interaction)
```

This works fine on Mac and menu is opened when user clicked by using right mouse button.

On the other hand, I need to open the same menu on a normal button click on some cases especially if the user is using the app on iPad. Is there any way to open the same context menu on normal button click/tap event?

Comment: What's wrong with default behaviour on 3D Touch, and long-press gestures?

Comment: On catalyst app, I need to open the menu by normal tap especially on mac version of the app. 3D touch is not always available on Macs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, official documentation clearly states that `UIContextMenuInteraction` handles user interaction by itself, so there is no official way to change this, at least for now - we provide *only* content, everything else is behind the scene.

From [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction)

**Declaration**

`class UIContextMenuInteraction : NSObject`

**Overview**

Use a UIContextMenuInteraction object to focus the user's attention on a specific portion of your content, and to provide actions for the user to perform on that content. *A context menu interaction object tracks Force Touch gestures on devices that support 3D Touch, and long-press gestures on devices that don't support it. When the appropriate gesture occurs, this object animates your content* to a new interface and displays the contextual menu that you supplied. UIKit manages all menu-related interactions and reports the selected action, if any, back to your app.